# Run output while input is still pending

Tags: c#, input, console, output

This is what I want to do:

1. Console asks for input
2. Console outputs things
3. Input can still be put any time while output is coming

So it basically does the following:

```
string message;
Console.WriteLine("Please enter your message");
message = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("While you're writing that, this is shown,");
Console.WriteLine("And you can continue to write as things are being outputted");
```

How could I achieve this functionality? Do I need to run multiple threads? What about sending input from one console window to the other?

Comment: Yes, this requires a second thread. I don't know yet what you mean with "from one console window to the other" - do you mean a completely different windows process?

Comment: Yeah, but if I can just input while output is coming in, that's fine too. I wouldn't really need a second console to serve as an inputbox... It would probably still require multiple threads.

Comment: I'm not even sure if you can have multiple consoles, however, yes: just put the writing into a `System.Threading.Task` and start the task just before you call Console.ReadLine().

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simple example using a [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424.aspx):

```
while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter number");
    var input = Console.ReadLine();
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
    {
        int n;
        if(Int32.TryParse(input, out n))
            for(int i=n; i>0; i--)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} -> {1}", n, i));
                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
    });
}
```

It's an endless loop that asks for a number. If you enter a number, the programm will start counting down, but you can enter the next number while the output is running.